# Relation between the condensation gap and the critical temperature in superconductors/holographic superconductors

Tags: superconductivity, ads-cft, holographic-principle

In some articles about holographic superconductors, it is written that when the condensation gap increases, the critical temperature decreases. For example, here:  https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP12(2020)192. (Please compare the left panels of Figs 1 and 2 in this paper.) Also listed below

[image]

[image]

As it is seen the condensation becomes larger by increasing $\alpha$ and the critical temperature becomes smaller (the black line in the bottom plot).

But as I understand, this is not true everywhere. For example, in Fig. 1 here: https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2009/10/010

[image]

The blue line $\alpha=0.2$ is located higher than the green line $\alpha=0.25$, but its critical temperature is not smaller.

[image]

I am really confused: If the condensation gap increases, does the critical temperature necessarily decrease? Is this a physical consequence? Or it may be violated in some cases and is not a general consequence?

Comment: In weak coupling (BCS) theory the energy gap, the order parameter expectation value, and $T_c$ are positively correlated. In strong coupling (as in holographic superconductors) more complicated behavior is possible.

Comment: Thank you very much. Could you please if possible introduce me a reference?

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much. Could you please if possible introduce me a reference?

Comment: @Kheeyal Any book about Condensed Matter Physics, for example 6.4 in  Altland, Simons "Condensed Matter Field Theory". Plenty of free stuff online too, e.g. https://www.phys.lsu.edu/~jarrell/COURSES/SOLID_STATE/Chap10/chap10.pdf

Comment: @Thomas Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your third picture above illustrates the anomalous behaviour of Chern-Simons limit case $\alpha=0.25$, where the correction to the AdS quadratic gravitational potential dependence is  a constant instead of $1/r^2$ . Indeed, [as explained](https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1126-6708/2009/10/010), the $\alpha=0.25$ Chern-Simons limit case “has a rather different and smoother profile near the horizon, therefore it is not surprising that decreasing the black hole mass in this case has more impact on the details of the scalar field”.
Looking at it from a condensed matter standpoint, the correspondence is between gravitational attraction (encoded in Einstein–Maxwell equations, but  modified so as to grow a BH hair), to electron repulsion (turning into attraction/aggregation in the superconducting case by whatever mechanism, e.g. BCS). Different “hairs” yield different temperature/condensation (e.g. Cooper pairs production) plots.

Comment: As I understood, this anomalous behavior should just occur at the Chern-Simons limit. But reproducing the figs in https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/JHEP12(2020)192, for smaller steps, I saw that this is not the case. Please see this link https://s6.uupload.ir/files/b_tycx.jpg and the zoomed version https://s6.uupload.ir/files/c_t6jx.jpg . From alpha=0.21 the condensation starts to decrease but the critical temperature does not start to increase until alpha=0.25 (https://s6.uupload.ir/files/a_f6s.jpg). Note that before alpha=0.21, the condensation increases with increasing alpha.

Comment: The behaviour is model-dependent. Here Herzog addresses a question similar to yours: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T3OSiipf9r8&t=4207s .